# ClassNotFoundException: javax.wsdl.extensions.ExtensibilityElement

Tags: java, spring, web-services, wsdl

I write a webservice follow [spring-ws tutorial](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/2.2.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#server), i get a error.

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:javax.wsdl.extensions.ExtensibilityElement`

But my path really have wsdl4j.jar.

[image][image]

EndpointConfig only have a bean that return a SimpleWsdl11Definition with orders.wsdl.

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdom2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Try use `wsdl4j:wsdl4j:1.6.2`. I use this version to follow the spring-ws-tutorial and it works for me!

Answer (score 4):

Add this to the pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using below pom.xml and it works, In case if you want to try.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <artifactId>spring-server-final</artifactId>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <groupId>spring-server-final</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-server-final</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-maven-milestone</id>
            <name>Springframework Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.2.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.ws.version>2.2.4.RELEASE</spring.ws.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.16</log4j.version>
        <apache.ws.version>1.6.19</apache.ws.version>
        <context.path>spring-server</context.path>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.ws.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-security</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.ws.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-xml</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.ws.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.xmlschema</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlschema-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.ws.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>spring-server-final</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible you are using different version. Please check whether your jar actually contains this class - 
javax.wsdl.extensions.ExtensibilityElement